Stripe React JS Error - Could not retrieve elements store due to unexpected error
I am building a website in nextjs and using custom form for payment.
For custom form I am using stripe elements, CardNumberElement, CardCVCElement and so on.
I am getting this error while I am calling elements.submit()

StripeProvide.ts
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { loadStripe, StripeElementsOptions } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import env from "@/config/env.config";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

const options: StripeElementsOptions = {
    mode: "payment",
    currency: "pkr",
    appearance: {},
};

const StripeProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({
    children,
}) => {
    return (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
            {children}
        </Elements>
    );
};

export default StripeProvider;


DonationForm.ts
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm, UseFormReturn } from "react-hook-form";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Form, FormField } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { donationSchema, DonationSchema } from "@/lib/schema";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { ArrowLeft } from "lucide-react";
import {
    CardCvcElement,
    CardExpiryElement,
    CardNumberElement,
    useElements,
    useStripe,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import payment from "@/api/payment";
import env from "@/config/env.config";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

type DonationFormComponent = (props: {}) => JSX.Element;

const stepsContent = {
    1: {
        header: {
            title: "Card Details",
            description: "Enter your card details.",
        },
        button: "Next",
    },
    2: {
        header: {
            title: "Donate",
            description:
                "Help us provide essential aid to families, children, and communities.",
        },
        button: "Donate",
    },
} as const;

const DonationForm: DonationFormComponent = (props) => {
    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState<1 | 2>(1);
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const form = useForm<DonationSchema>({
        resolver: zodResolver(donationSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            amount: 0,
            cardHolderName: "",
            email: "",
            fullName: "",
            postalCode: "",
        },
    });

    const pathname = usePathname();

    async function onSubmit(data: DonationSchema) {
        console.log(`~~~ Submitting ~~~`, data);
        if (elements == null || stripe === null) {
            console.log(`Stripe Or Elements isn't properly initialized!`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`~~~ Elements and Stripe ~~~`);

        const cardNumberElement = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);
        const cardExpiryElement = elements.getElement(CardExpiryElement);
        const cardCvcElement = elements.getElement(CardCvcElement);

        console.log("CardNumberElement:", cardNumberElement);
        console.log("CardExpiryElement:", cardExpiryElement);
        console.log("CardCvcElement:", cardCvcElement);

        if (!cardNumberElement || !cardExpiryElement || !cardCvcElement) {
            console.error("Stripe elements are not rendered.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            const { error: submitError } = await elements.submit();
            if (submitError) {
                console.log({ submitError });
                return;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Unexpected Error:", error);
        }

        const { clientSecret } = await payment.init({
            amount: data.amount,
            email: data.email,
            fullName: data.fullName,
        });

        const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements,
            clientSecret,
            confirmParams: {
                return_url: `${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}${pathname}#success`,
            },
        });

        if (error) {
            toast.error(error.message);
            return;
        }

        toast.success("Payment successful");
    }

    const content = stepsContent[currentStep];

    return (
        <div className="absolute top-[20%] right-[10%] flex flex-col z-[100] shadow-lg bg-white w-[30vw] rounded-lg px-7 py-6 ml-[110px] self-start">
            <div className="flex flex-row items-start justify-between">
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 mb-5">
                    <div className="space-x-2 flex flex-row items-center">
                        {currentStep === 2 ? (
                            <ArrowLeft
                                className="text-stone-500 cursor-pointer"
                                onClick={() => setCurrentStep(1)}
                            />
                        ) : null}
                        <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold">{content.header.title}</h2>
                    </div>

                    <h3 className="text-md font-normal text-stone-500">
                        {content.header.description}
                    </h3>
                </div>

                <div className="flex my-3 gap-1">
                    {Array(2)
                        .fill(0)
                        .map((_, i) => i + 1)
                        .map((step) => (
                            <span
                                onClick={() => setCurrentStep(step as 1 | 2)}
                                key={step}
                                className={cn(
                                    "w-8 cursor-pointer bg-[#E9EDEE] h-1 rounded-md",
                                    {
                                        "bg-background": currentStep === step,
                                    }
                                )}
                            ></span>
                        ))}
                </div>
            </div>

            <Form {...form}>
                <form
                    onSubmit={(e) => {
                        if (currentStep === 1) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return setCurrentStep(2);
                        }
                        console.log("Lets submit");
                        return form.handleSubmit(onSubmit, (error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        })(e);
                    }}
                    className="space-y-2 gap-y-2 flex flex-col w-full relative"
                >
                    <div
                        className={cn(
                            "flex flex-row items-center justify-start gap-0 flex-1 min-w-[200%] overflow-visible",
                            {
                                "translate-x-0": currentStep === 1,
                                "translate-x-[-20.5%]": currentStep === 2,
                            }
                        )}
                    >
                        <div
                            className={cn("", {
                                "opacity-0": currentStep === 2,
                                "w-[50%] flex-2 flex flex-col gap-4": currentStep === 1,
                            })}
                        >
                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="cardHolderName"
                                render={({ field }) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="flex-1 w-[100%] flex flex-col gap-1">
                                            <Label className="text-primary-content font-normal text-[16px]">
                                                Cardholder Name
                                                <span className="text-red-800">*</span>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Input {...field} placeholder="Enter name on your card" />
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                }}
                            />

                            <div className="flex-1 w-[100%] flex flex-col gap-1">
                                <Label className="text-primary-content font-normal text-[16px]">
                                    Card Number
                                    <span className="text-red-800">*</span>
                                </Label>
                                <CardNumberElement className="w-[100%] rounded-xl border border-input px-3 py-3 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50" />
                            </div>

                            <div className="flex-1 w-[100%] flex flex-row gap-4">
                                <div className="flex flex-col gap-1 flex-1">
                                    <Label className="text-primary-content font-normal text-[16px]">
                                        Expiration
                                        <span className="text-red-800">*</span>
                                    </Label>
                                    <CardExpiryElement className="w-[100%] rounded-xl border border-input px-3 py-3 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50" />
                                </div>

                                <div className="flex-1 w-[100%] flex flex-col gap-1">
                                    <Label className="text-primary-content font-normal text-[16px]">
                                        CVC
                                        <span className="text-red-800">*</span>
                                    </Label>
                                    <CardCvcElement
                                        onReady={(element) => {
                                            console.log(element);
                                        }}
                                        className="w-[100%] rounded-xl border border-input px-3 py-3 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="postalCode"
                                render={({ field }) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="flex-1 w-[100%] flex flex-col gap-1">
                                            <Label className="text-primary-content font-normal text-[16px]">
                                                Postal code
                                                <span className="text-red-800">*</span>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Input {...field} placeholder="Postal or zip code" />
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div
                            className={cn("", {
                                "opacity-0": currentStep === 1,
                                "w-[50%] flex-2 flex flex-col gap-4": currentStep === 2,
                            })}
                        >
                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="fullName"
                                render={({ field }) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col gap-1">
                                            <Label className="text-primary-content font-normal text-[16px]">
                                                Full Name
                                                <span className="text-red-800">*</span>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Input {...field} placeholder="Enter full name" />
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                }}
                            />
                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="email"
                                render={({ field }) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col gap-1">
                                            <Label className="text-primary-content font-normal text-[16px]">
                                                Email Address
                                                <span className="text-red-800">*</span>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Input {...field} placeholder="Enter email address" />
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                }}
                            />

                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="amount"
                                render={({ field }) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col gap-1">
                                            <Label className="text-primary-content font-normal text-[16px]">
                                                Amount
                                                <span className="text-red-800">*</span>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Input {...field} placeholder="Enter amount" />
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* <StepComponent form={form} /> */}
                    <Button
                        className="max-sm:w-full text-base font-semibold"
                        type="submit"
                        size="lg"
                        variant={"secondary"}
                        disabled={form.formState.isSubmitting}
                    >
                        {content.button}
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </Form>

            {currentStep === 2 && (
                <p className="px-2 text-center text-wrap text-[18px] pt-4 text-stone-500">
                    We&apos;ll never share your information with anyone.
                </p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default DonationForm;

Home.ts
<StripeProvider>
  <DonationForm />
</StripeProvider>

I have tried adding various logs to check whether elements are being loaded or not.

It seems like this is Stripe's code that is throwing the error. I'd suggest writing into their support team to have them investigate this further: https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true. I would also recommend including the versions of stripe-react-js and stripe-js that are being used in your project when you reach out.
